# How am I supposed to pass the time?

Tags: deadly-premonition

In the game, there are number of events that only occur during specific time slots. For example, at one point there was a town meeting scheduled between 15:00 and 17:00. In this instance, when I was notified of this event, it was around 09:00. So I had some time to kill.

To pass the time naturally, you have a few options. You can run around town, whittling your time away on side-quests, but there are only so many. You can take a nap, but the naps are broken up into 3-hour incremental chunks. You can just let the in-game clock run up, but waiting for an in-game hour to pass seems to take about 20 minutes of real time.

It seems apparent then that there must be some sort of way to conveniently "wait" à la Fallout 3, Skyrim, etc. Otherwise, lining up a specific time in the game would be an extremely tedious affair. I'm obviously missing something.

**How do you pass time quickly in Deadly Premonition?**

Comment: header threw me off haha

Comment: http://deadlypremonition.wikia.com/wiki/Gameplay#Time. Aside from sleeping, you can also smoke cigarettes.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the time by smoking a pack of [cigarettes](http://deadlypremonition.wikia.com/wiki/Cigarette) for as long as you like, similar to the wait function in Fallout 3.

However, make sure you eat/drink coffee before starting on a pack or the game will automatically terminate the smoking scene and warn you that you need to get something to eat/some sleep first. The game will also interrupt the smoking when it's midnight because:

> the zombies of the Other World just love hanging out at this time of the day.

Comment: For completion's sake, you can put the reason that smoking's interrupted at midnight behind a spoiler tag, which you can do by typing `>!` and putting text after it. :)